# v-for not working on array - Property or method "dailyData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to list daily weather data in a table

```
<tr :v-for="dailyData in weatherData.daily">
  <td>{{ dailyData }}</td>
</tr>
```

Where weatherData is a data property.

But it's giving me error - Property or method "dailyData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Data showing in console.log(weatherData.daily) perfectly like below

```
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
0: {…}
1: {…}
2: {…}
3: {…}
4: {…}
5: {…}
6: {…}
7: {…}
length: 8
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(8), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-for` and other [directives](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Directives) should not be prefixed with colons:

- also be sure to add a `key` value to each element as required by `v-for`

```js
<tr v-for="(dailyData, index) in weatherData.daily" :key="index">
  <td>{{ dailyData }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: then it gives error - Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
<tr v-for="(dailyData,index) in weatherData.daily" :key="index">
  <td>{{ dailyData }}</td>
</tr>
```